# Using #define to differentiate between calling classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to call some method if and only if the method is called from the unit test class. I have implemented following code for that:

```
    #ifndef UNIT_TESTING

    NSLog(@"inside unit testing");

#endif
```

this is not called when i am calling from the controller class . What should i do to so this loop is get called ? How can i set the macro to the UNIT_TESTING

Comment: If your code must be aware of being tested, your unit tests are probably wrong.

Comment: How to make the code aware of its being tested ? I did not put any extra logic in unit test case for that my test case is:                    -(void)testShouldNotReturnPathWhenKeyIsEmpty
{
    NSString *url=@"";
    STAssertNil([cacheManager getResources:url],@"path is not nil");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your unit test targeting build settings (in X-code), add the following to the "Preprocessor Macros Not Used in Precompiled Headers" option under the "Apple LLVM 3.1" section (or the equivalent GCC section if you are still using that):

```
UNIT_TESTING=1
```